# Is there something wrong in the error handling of this function?

Tags: c, error-handling

Is there something wrong in the error handling of this function? Specifically, I guess in these 2 lines:

```
if (!src || !nodeCopy)
    return NULL;
```

Is it correct to check that two pointers at once?

I sent my program to my teacher and he said the error handling was wrong in some functions, in example this.

**This code is written in C**

```
Node * node_copy(const Node * src) {

Node *nodeCopy;

nodeCopy = (Node*) malloc (sizeof (Node));

if (!src || !nodeCopy)
    return NULL;

nodeCopy->id = src->id;
nodeCopy->nConnect = src->nConnect;
strcpy (nodeCopy->name, src->name);

return nodeCopy;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it has a memory leak if `src` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're handling both a NULL parameter value and a NULL return from `malloc` the same way.  You probably want to do something different for each of them.

In the case that `src` is NULL, it most likely makes sense to return NULL from the function.  If `malloc` returns NULL however, that typically means something went very wrong and the program should `exit`.

```
Node * node_copy(const Node * src) {
    Node *nodeCopy;

    if (!src)
        return NULL;

    nodeCopy = malloc(sizeof (Node));
    if (!nodeCopy) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    nodeCopy->id = src->id;
    nodeCopy->nConnect = src->nConnect;
    strcpy (nodeCopy->name, src->name);

    return nodeCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `src` is null, you'll leak the memory you allocated for `nodeCopy`. Checking `src` before you allocate the memory will avoid this.

Also, if this were production code, you'd have trouble generating a reasonable error message there without splitting it into two separate checks anyway.

Comment: Oh, ok, I haven't realised that. Thank you very much.